# sublime text 2 open file from find results keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2

In the Sublime Text 2 "Find in Files" results, a box is drawn around wherever your search term appears. Double clicking within that box opens the file and focuses your cursor on that line.

Is there any way to achieve this using only your keyboard?

I understand you could use cmd+p to open file then ctrl+g to goto line, but I was hoping there was a single combo you could use to go directly to the result, like the double click offers.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41567906/293280.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally <kbd>F4</kbd> & <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> are used for cycling through found results. But if you set your cursor position to one line upper of what you want to go and press <kbd>F4</kbd> it opens the file and sets your cursor position to start of that line.

And if you want to change shortcut put this in your "Default (OSX).sublime-keymap" file in User directory and change <kbd>F4</kbd> to shortcut you want:

```
{ "keys": ["f4"], "command": "next_result" }
```

Edit:
Just noticed <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> goes to right result (as long as cursor is not at first column of line. In that case previous result shows up) even if your cursor is 'at' the results itself. So that's better for this question.

Second edit:
"User" directory is "/Users/Username/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User" which also can be accessed through Sublime Text 2 (Command Palette (<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) or through menu (Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Browse Packages...))